# ActiveRecord : Hide column while returning object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Is there an out-of-the-box way to always hide/remove a column (say, User.password) while returning an ActiveRecord object?

Comment: In what context? Is this a JSON api? Rails console? If it's the latter, there's nothing you can do, as the user effectively has access to the source code and database.

Comment: @ZachKemp JSON Api. Most accurately, OAuth Token. I thought about adding a 1-1 relationship just to store that but thought about asking first if there's a neat way.

Comment: What are you using to serialize your user model (ie, how is your api implemented)?

Comment: @ZachKemp retrieves data from the database (User.find(:id)) and passes objects to controller which renders as JSON `render :json => @users`

Comment: You are not using plain text passwords, are you? or else you know exactly what to change.

Comment: +1 @fotanus, but the question may apply to other attributes that shouldn't/needn't be serialized

Comment: @fotanus Even for encrypted password it would be foolish to return them in the API! But in this case, it's Facebook OAuth tokens (which could easily be hijacked if returned).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using the built-in serialization, you can override the `as_json` method on your model to pass in additional default options:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def as_json(options = {})
    super(options.merge({ except: [:password, :oauth_token] }))
  end
end
```

There are probably better serialization tools out there - if you are looking for more fine-grained control I would recommend checking out `active_model_serializers` or `rabl`.

Comment: I'll checkout `active_model_serializers`. But overriding `as_json` is what I've been looking for. Thank you !

Comment: This solves the problem but if I do something like this `@manager.to_json(include: :user)` I am still getting the password_digest filed in the user object

Comment: yes I'm also still getting same as @Sandeep said, any solution??

Comment: undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 8):

You can hide a specific attribute at serialization time using `:except`:

```
render json: @users, except: [:password, :other]
```

Alternatively, you can use [`after_initialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) for this, and move the data into a non-serialized attribute:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :hidden_password, :hidden_other
  after_initialize :hide_columns

  def hide_columns
    [:password, :other].each do |c|
      send("hidden_#{c}=", send(c))
      send("#{c}=", nil)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm currently using a conditional layout with `except`but `after_initialize` seems to be neat.

Answer (score 8):

### Did you get to this page because you are trying to hide plain text passwords?

**STOP! you are doing it wrong.**

**You should not, never, ever keep passwords in plain text.**

Chances are that your server has or will have some kind of flaw and hackers will get your clients passwords. Think for a while:

- What will you tell them?
- How will they react?
- What are the outcomes for your business?

Since you are now a new person and are searching about the correct way to store passwords, you might [want to read this nice article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html)

Comment: Even for MD5/encrypted passwords, as I said, it would be quite dumb to return them in the API view :)

Comment: Yes, this is not for you - I read your comments on the question. It is for people that google to here.

Answer (score 0):

8 years later, Rails 5+ has a way to ignore/hide columns from model:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Migration.new.create_table :my_pages do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.string :body
  t.string :search_tsv
end

class MyPage < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.ignored_columns = %w[search_tsv]
end

MyPage.new

# => #<MyPage:0x00007fa4693b8278 id: nil, title: nil, body: nil>

class MyPage2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'my_pages'
  self.ignored_columns = %w[body search_tsv]
end

MyPage2.new

# => #<MyPage2:0x00007fa46845f808 id: nil, title: nil>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with plain ActiveRecord (without Rails)

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { select(Game.column_names - ["some_field"]) }
end
```

To make "unscoped" requests just do like:

```
Game.unscoped.all
```